# Do nested field object in document with huge amount of nested values have a good performance?

Tags: elasticsearch, nested, nested-fields

I would like to index document with [nested field](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/nested.html). There will be some cases when some documents is going to have more than 10k elements (even 80k). Also I'm going to query this index with **inner_hits** using **from** and **size** parameters (I need to paginate nested objects). My question is : Is it a good approach to use nested field when I need to paginate the list with huge amount of data or it will be better to denormalize the model ?

Comment: My vote is to denormalize model if it is possible. From your task I assume that you mast nested fields as top level documents with additional field like "parent_id".

Comment: Same as Alex, 10K-80K nested documents to paginate through them is clearly as sub-optimal as it gets. Denormalization is key!

Comment: Alex, yes I have parent object with parent_id and some additional properties and lots of child object with different properties

Comment: You're right I will go with denormalization. Thanks for comments